# Stream Analytics -not seeing the output

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I use Stream Analytic to save the EventHub data into an SQL DataBase.
Even though I can see that I have both input and output requests, when I write a query to see the data from the output table I can see just 200 empty rows!! So I send data to this table, but are just NULL values

I think the problem may bethe query between input and output because my output table is empty :(. This is how I wrote it:

> SELECT id,sensor,val FROM EventHubInput

Could there be another problem?
I have to mention that my EventHub is the link between a Meshlium and Azure.This is why I think my problem can be also from the frame I send from Meshlium.

I really don't know what to do. HELP ?!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any output.

```
SELECT id,sensor,val 
OUTPUT YourSQLOutput
FROM EventHubInput
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream Analytics queries' default output is `output`.

So if your SQL DB alias is `SQLDbOutput`, it won't work. You should specify it yourself:

```
SELECT id,sensor,val
INTO SQLDbOutput
FROM EventHubInput
```

The editor in Azure should tell you the names of your inputs and outputs on the left.

---

Also make sure your events in Event Hub contain those properties (id, sensor, val), and that the SQL DB contains columns with the same names.

Comment: This was one of the problems. My query didn't include "INTO outputDB". And I solved the problem by rewriting the frame send from my device ( Meshlium) .